# using buildear with multiple file aliases

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I am using the buildear functionality in tibco to include multiple file alisases
I am able to include the alias of the projlib but i have multiple jar files created as file aliases.
can you help how can i add them

currently the command i am using is

```
buildear -x -v C:\CLEStubs.projlib /Deployment/abc.archive -o c:\abc.archive -p C:\test\
```

but i have some other jar files and it fails in validation

Initiating validation...

Error: no alias for 
Error: no alias for 
Error: no alias for 
Error: no alias for 
An external alias could not be mapped.: The external file alias 'uuid-3.2-sources.jar' could not be mapped.
(4) errors and (22) warnings found
Errors were detected in the project. The archive was not built
Aborting.

can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the parameter -a:

> -a (optional) specify a properties file containing aliases for DTL library locations

Aliases file format is:
NameOfTheAlias=/path/to/the/library

`buildear -x -v C:\CLEStubs.projlib /Deployment/abc.archive -a /path/to/aliasPropertyFile -o c:\abc.archive -p C:\test\`

And the alias property file should contain entries like:
tibco.alias.uuid-3.2-sources.jar=/path/to/Fahrplan.jar

You can export these entries in Designer.